# BeautifulSoup - Parsing issue on a seemingly simple situation

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm new to BeautifulSoup and just created my first script yesterday. Here's a bit of code that is not getting the result I'm expecting:

```
html = """<a href="http://www.example.com"><b>Text</b> and more text</a>"""
exampleSoup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print exampleSoup.a.string
```

I'm expecting to obtain...

```
<b>Text</b> and more text
```

But Im getting "None". What am I assuming incorrectly?

I ran diagnose on the html variable but (as expected) this doesn't seem to be a parsing problem as everything is pretty much as its originally on the string.

Answer (score 3):

The [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) would return you `None` if there is *more than a single child of an element*:

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None

What you meant is to use `str(exampleSoup.a)` to get the HTML representation of an element.

Or, if you want to get the complete text including the children, use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
exampleSoup.a.get_text()
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! This answer helped and I forgot to write back to let you know.